# How to create solr core in Dockerfile and may the local directory to container /opt/solr directory

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose, dockerfile, solr5

I am using the following `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` to build the solr container

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  solr:
    container_name: test.solr
    #image: solr:5.5
    build: .build/solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
  volumes:
      - ./data/solr:/opt/solr/server/solr
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM solr:5.5

WORKDIR /opt/solr
RUN solr create -c drupal-solr
```

But the container can't be built with the following error

> ERROR: Service 'solr' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c solr
>   create -c drupal-search -p 8983' returned a non-zero code: 1

I have to remove the `solr create` command from the Dockerfile to allow the container to be built properly.

However when I switch on the container, the solr container will exit with the following error

> Solr home directory /opt/solr/server/solr must contain a solr.xml
>   file!

How should I update my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile to pre-create the core, and map the core directory to the local directory?

Comment: i have the same issue with the solr.xml file error.
i'm using volumes and pointing a relative directory with my cores in but fails (windows)

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the build and start order.

To avoid this issue you could use:

```
FROM solr:6.6-alpine
RUN precreate-core drupal-solr
```